# PHP: map array with explode keys involved

Tags: php, html, arrays, explode

after trying to solve this with multiple foreach loops I still cant figure out how to map `$arr` to `$arr_mapped`

I need to explode the keys of `$arr` to get an element with up to three new keys to create `$arr_mapped`

```php
<?php

$arr = [
  'abc:quantity' => 1,
  'abc:variant' => 'blue',
  'xyz:quantity' => 2,
  'foo:quantity' => null
];

$arr_mapped = [
  [
    'id' => 'abc',
    'quantity' => 1,
    'variant' => 'blue'
  ],
  [
    'id' => 'xyz',
    'quantity' => 2,
  ]
];
```

background: I want to let a user bulk add predefined shopping items in a `<form>`
Its a custom PHP Shop.

```html
<form>

<input name="abc:quantity" value="1">
<input name="abc:variant" value="blue">
<input name="xyz:quantity" value="2">
<input name="foo:quantity" value="">

<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

thanks for any suggestions

Comment: In your input array you have quantity and variant for `abc`. In your output array you also have variant of `green`. How can you distinguish between the quantities for `abc` in blue and `abc` in green?

Comment: Why isn't `foo` in the output anywhere? Is it because the value is `null`?

Comment: I suspect your example output is for a different input. Please show a correct pair.

Comment: thanks for the replies, you absolutely right, my example didnt make sense, I fixed it now hopfully, and yes foo is filtered out because its `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will produce the output you want based on the input you provided in your example (which doesn't seem to match the output in your example):

```
$arr = [
  'abc:quantity' => 1,
  'abc:variant' => 'blue',
  'xyz:quantity' => 2,
  'foo:quantity' => null
];

$arr_mapped = array_values(array_reduce(array_keys($arr), function($map, $key) use ($arr) {
    [$id,$field] = explode(':', $key);
    $map[$id]['id'] = $id;
    $map[$id][$field] = $arr[$key];
    return $map;
}, []));
```

result:

```
[
  [
    'id' => 'abc',
    'quantity' => 1,
    'variant' => 'blue'
  ],
  [
    'id' => 'xyz',
    'quantity' => 1,
  ],
  [
    'id' => 'foo',
    'quantity' => null,
  ]
];
```

Comment: thanks for your input and code, my example didnt make sense, I edited the code
your code seems very promising, I will try this, my php is quite limited, I'm more confident in js, so I will look into the `array_reduce` fn

Comment: thanks so much, I sucessfully implemented you code in my project, and learned about `array_reduce` fn